# OpenGL scene centering problems

Tags: opengl, 3d, glut

I'm trying to make a scene where I am looking at the XY plane with Z coming towards and away from the camera view. I want to see objects that are further away at a different size than objects that are in front of my face so I imagine I am supposed to use gluPerspective for this. I should have some axes on my screen coming from the origin out, however, I don't see anything at all. I had it working with a bunch of translations but I want to make sure I understand how to manipulate this properly because that was all guess and check before.

```
void resizeWindow(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f, (GLfloat)newWidth / (GLfloat)newHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

glPushMatrix();
glColor4ub(0, 120, 20, 255);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(2.85f, 0.10f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(2.85f, -0.10f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(2.85f, 0.0f, 0.10f);
glVertex3f(2.85f, 0.0f, -0.10f);
glVertex3f(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 2.85f, 0.10f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 2.85f, -0.10f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.10f, 2.85f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.10f, 2.85f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glVertex3f(0.10f, 0.0f, 2.85f);
glVertex3f(-0.10f, 0.0f, 2.85f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.10f, 2.85f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, -0.10f, 2.85f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try to run the code, but from a quick glance :

- Remove the glPushMatrix(). You're not popping it anywhere ... and not modifying them either
- Your "eye" coordinates (0.0, 0.0, -1.0) seem to be a bit too close to the original give your axises are 3.0 unit in length. Try (0.0, 0.0, -20.0) or so.

Comment: Shouldn't I at least see the beginning of the line?